# Is it possible to obtain the legacy console edition of Minecraft for the Switch? If so, how do I get it?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, nintendo-switch

Apparently, after the Better Together update, you cannot get the original console edition. If there is a workaround, I would love to hear it. But I heard that if you get Bedrock Edition after the update, then if you delete it and then reinstall it (not the save data), it will treat it like you just bought it, so you'll be able to access the console edition. I'm wondering if that's true.

Weird side note: I bought mine in 2021, and when I plugged the game cart in and booted it up, it launched me into the console version, and at the bottom, it said something like, "Upgrade for free," and I was wondering why didn't it just go straight to Bedrock Edition?

Summary: **I have heard that it is impossible to obtain the legacy console edition of MC for the switch. Is that true? If not, how do I get it?**